# subnet_id value for multiple subnet in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

```
varaible.tf


variable "subnets" {
  type = map(any)
  default = {
    subnet1 = {
      "key"              = "subnet_1"
      "address_prefixes" = ["10.20.30.0/24"]
    }

    subnet2 = {
      "key"              = "subnet_2"
      "address_prefixes" = ["10.20.40.0/24"]
    }

  }
}



main.tf


resource "azurerm_subnet" "subnet1" {
  for_each             = var.subnets
  name                 = each.value["key"]
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.azureDevops.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet1.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value["address_prefixes"]
}
```

Want to attach security group to all my subnet. its more than one value. its throwing error
for subnet_id.

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {

subnet_id = [for subnet in azurerm_subnet.subnet1 : subnet.id]
network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.tamopsnsg.id
}
```

its throwing error for subnet_id value. how to attach to more than one subnet?

Comment: You would have to use `for_each` in the second resource as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve here is a typical use-case for [chaining `for_each` between resources](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each#chaining-for_each-between-resources), where the map value created by one `for_each` resource becomes the `for_each` value for a downstream resource.

For example:

```
variable "subnets" {
  # NOTE: Better to specify an exact type constraint
  # so that Terraform can give you better feedback
  # when you make a mistake elsewhere in the
  # configuration.
  type = map(object({
    key              = string
    address_prefixes = set(string)
  }))
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  for_each = var.subnets

  name                 = each.value.key
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.azure_devops.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet1.name
  address_prefixes     = each.value.address_prefixes
}

resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "example" {
  for_each = azurerm_subnet.example

  subnet_id                 = each.value.id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.tamopsnsg.id
}
```

This relies on the fact that `azurerm_subnet.subnet1` is, because that resource uses `for_each`, a map from instance keys to objects representing each of the subnets. The instance keys will exactly match the keys of `var.subnets` due to how `for_each` works, and so for each of the subnets you declared you'll also declare a corresponding security group association:

- `azurerm_subnet.example["subnet1"]` corresponds with `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.example["subnet1"]`
- `azurerm_subnet.example["subnet2"]` corresponds with `azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association.example["subnet2"]`

`each.value` in the *association* resource block will be the object representing the subnet you declared rather than an element of `var.subnets`, and so you can access `each.value.id` to get the remote object ID of the corresponding subnet.